# Неоднородные приложения - балерина и народная артистка?

Tags: пунктуация

> В Германии в возрасте 89 лет скончалась балерина, народная артистка СССР Майя Плисецкая.

По-моему, здесь неоднородные приложения и потому запятая не нужна. Разве что балерина - определяемое слово. Но это как-то неестественно звучит.

Answer (score 2):

В Германии в возрасте 89 лет скончалась балерина, народная артистка СССР Майя Плисецкая. В такой последовательности приложения считаются однородными и  разделяются запятой.

Вообще говоря, однородные приложения обозначают **сходные** или **сближенные** признаки и раскрывают **общую тему**. Следует отметить, что чаще ряд приложений **считается однородным**, так как функцию приложения в  неоднородном ряду труднее определить,  и поэтому он строится в **более строгой последовательности**.

Сравним: В Германии в возрасте 89 лет скончалась  народная артистка СССР балерина Майя Плисецкая.

#### Другие примеры

Молодая женщина, поэтесса Иванова  читала свои новые стихи.

Учитель военной прогимназии, коллежский регистратор Лев Пустяков обитал рядом с другом своим, поручиком Леденцовым.